# Using Mailgun with osTicket

Tags: api

I'd like to use Mailgun with osTicket. However osTicket is requiring a valid API key, generated by osTicket.

I haven't found a way to add the API key to Mailgun's routes. The action I set in Mailgun is:

```
forward("https://domain.com/support/api/tickets.email")
```

Mailgun is of course trying to forward the mail. The system log of osTicket is showing me API Error (401) Valid API key required.

Is there a way to send the API key together with the action?

If not, any other open source ticketing system that might work with Mailgun?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Mailgun doesn't have ability to inject HTTP X-header, you can simply forward the emails to an email inbox and let osTicket fetch the emails via IMAP/POP3.

That said, we're planning on writing a Mailgun plugin to interface with osTicket and by-pass the need for an API key.

Comment: Yes, that is a working solution. We forward to our email inboxes and pipe the messages from there.

Comment: Any news about a Mailgun plugin? Don't seem to find one yet...

Answer (score 0):

You could also set up a proxy server that will receive the HTTP request from Mailgun and do the necessary adjustments before passing the request on to osTicket.